# Sharepoint-Hosted apps under https

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app, https

I have developed an app which is supposed to be hosted on a secure website (https).
The DNS records and the SP Configuration is done successfully. My app works fine under the normal http url, but i get a This Connection is Untrusted error when i access a page with the my custom business app.

- Portal URL: https://subdomain.mysite.com
- App URL: https://app-5d1db788f8b3af.apps.othersite.com

> Note: subdomain.mysite.com and app-5d1db788f8b3af.apps.othersite.com have the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this by now but...

You mentioned two different domains and also mentioned that they shared the same IP.

IIS links the SSL certificate with the IP address and not the host header (as the host header is protected by the certificate when the request reaches IIS), and, unless the certificate is valid for both domains, one of them will fail the validation.

You have two alternatives:

**1**

- Add a second IP to the machine
- Generate a new SSL certificate for your App domain
- Link this certificate to that domain in the new IP in IIS

  - You might need a new web application to host the app domain, or add another binding to your current Web Application linked to the new IP

**2**

- Get a new certificate that is valid for both domains
- Use the new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Extending your https web application to a new Zone of http?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276325%28v=office.15%29.aspx

We used this concept in order to search our https site.  We extended our web application to mirror the same IP and set the port to 80.

Comment: Just did the extend now as instructed in the article. but still have the same issue.